# Don't work Loading Related Data when i filter "Include" entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following models

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonRole> PersonRoles { get; set; }

}

public class RoleInDuty
{
    public int roleInDutyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int typeOfDutyId { get; set; }
    public TypeOfDuty typeOfDuty { get; set; }
    public List<PersonRole> PersonRoles { get; set; }

}
public class PersonRole
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int RoleInDutyId { get; set; }
    public RoleInDuty RoleInDuty { get; set; }
}
```

I load all people with their roles according entered typeOfDutyId:

```
var temp = _context.Persons.Select(s => new
  {
    Person = s,
    PersonRoles= s.PersonRoles
      .Where(p => p.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == this.typeOfDuty.typeOfDutyId)
      .ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

But i need load RoleInDuty too. I try the following code:

```
var temp = _context.Persons.
  .Include(p=>p.PersonRoles)
    .ThenInclude(b=>b.RoleInDuty)
  .Select(s => new
  {
    Person = s,
    PersonRoles= s.PersonRoles
      .Where(p => p.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == this.typeOfDuty.typeOfDutyId)
      .ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

But it is does not work, VS throw error

> InvalidOperationException: variable 'ct' of type
>   'System.Threading.CancellationToken' referenced from scope '', but it
>   is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the behaviour is the same as in EFCore, 
Include  (& ThenInclude) are ignored if you select only some part of the entity (because you use an anonymous type : `new { ... }`).

Maybe you can try :

```
var temp = _context.Persons.
  .Include(p=>p.PersonRoles)
    .ThenInclude(b=>b.RoleInDuty)
  .ToList();

var result = temp.Select(s => new
  {
    Person = s,
    PersonRoles= s.PersonRoles
      .Where(p => p.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == this.typeOfDuty.typeOfDutyId)
      .ToList()
  }).ToList()
```

This has for effect to load all the entity & dependencies, and then map it to an anonymous type.

Comment: Its work but  You are getting all the data from the db loading them in memory and doing the filter. I'm trying to avoid loading all the data.